# Running commands remotely and script not exiting on error

Tags: ksh, error-handling, here-document

I have a simple script which takes the first argument as a hostname and tries to connect to it and run some commands then saves the output locally.

But whenever I pass an invalid hostname and it fails to connect, it makes an empty /tmp/${1}_output.txt file even though it should just exit the script?

```
#!/bin/ksh

set -e

ssh $1 $(which ksh) << 'EOF' | tee /tmp/${1}_output.txt
(run commands on remote server)
EOF
```

Comment: That is the way it works. `tee` does not rely on any statuses and file is created to log anything before we know about `ssh` exit status. You can check ssh exit status and delete file if no connection has been made.

Comment: Note `which ksh` is done on client side and result is passed to the server
where ksh may not be on the same path